# Kernel density estimation for frequency data on polygon level

Tags: heat-map, resolution, kernel-density, spatial-analysis, hot-spot

I would like to make kernel density estimations for a variety of influencing factors on crime, but I do only have frequency data on polygon level, e.g. number of drug markets on county level.
For all kinds of kernel density estimations (KDE) or hotspot analysis, point data are required as input. Do you think I can nonetheless make such analysis and if yes, how?

My workaround would be to use the centroid of each polygon as point input features and set a weighting scheme to the number of observations. Do you think this is a valid approach in terms of usefulness of the models?

For the implementation I can work with any kind of GIS software or programming language (R, python).

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you have a regular lattice, you are imposing an arbitrary aerial unit, representing an aggregated process that does not match the scale that would be inferred with the KDE. This could potentially represent two well known statistical issues, the MAUP and, depending on the scale mismatch, Ecological Fallacy. You functionality have an arbitrary conditional spatial process, imposed by the polygon aggregation, that can't be accounted for in the kernel density estimate.

You could perform something like a LISA, Geits-Ord or Besag-L by building Wij spatial weights matrix based on Nth order polygon neighbor contingency. This would result in what you are referring to as a "hotspot analysis". These analysis can be done with the R spdep package.